# Mysql: explain returns more rows than the actual number

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

I have a table, which contains 40 M rows by counting.

```
select count(*) from xxxs;
returns 38000389
```

but the explain:

```
mysql> explain select * from xxxs where s_uuid = "21eaef";
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | xxxs  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 56511776 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
```

why the rows is 56M which is much larger than 40 M?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

1, the above query may take several minutes. is it normal? How to tune the performance?

2, I plan to create an index on s_uuid. I guess it will improve the performance. Am I right?

Comment: 56 million.  40 million.  They're close enough for query planning purposes.

Comment: You're comparing the results of 2 different queries - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxs;` and `SELECT * FROM xxxs WHERE s_uuid = "21eaef";` - so the number of rows may be different between them. Though I would've expected your `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxs;` to return more rows because it doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. In terms of adding indexes, I always recommend reading through http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql to determine which columns to index. So yes, if your queries often have `WHERE s_uuid = ?` then adding an index to `s_uuid` will speed up the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "rows" in `EXPLAIN` is an estimate based on statistics that were gathered in the recent past.  The value is rarely exact; sometimes it is even off by more than a factor of two.

Still, the estimate is *usually* "good enough" for the Optimizer to decide how to perform the query.

Another place to see this estimate of row count is via

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'xxxs';
```

(As mentioned in a Comment) Adding this is *likely* to speed up `select * from xxxs where s_uuid = "21eaef";`:

```
INDEX(s_uuid)
```

I say "likely to" because, if a lot of rows have `s_uuid = "21eaef"`, the Optimizer will shun the index and simply scan the entire table rather than bouncing back and forth from the index's BTree and the data's BTree.  You can see the "shun" in `EXPLAIN` by having `Possible keys = idx_uuid` but `key = NULL`.

There *will* be cases where the Optimizer makes the 'wrong' choice.  But we can discuss that in another Q&A.

Comment: so what is the best way to have these statistics updated on regular basis or to better auto-update them?

Comment: @OAH - Beginning with 5.6.6, InnoDB automatically does a good job of keeping the statistics up to date.  You can use `ANALYZE TABLE`, which is very fast, as often as you wish, but I think that is a wast of time.